# Jquery accordion, next and previous wizard, how to get previous and next sections?

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion

I have a Jquery accordion which works fine. Sections get expanded/collapsed when clicked on respective headers. But I want to add the functionality so that when I click on "next" button it opens up the next section and clicking "Previous" button takes me back to previous section.

This has been done on this page http://jquery.bassistance.de/accordion/demo/?p=1.1.2 (last example) but not sure how do I implement the same in my case.

Any suggestions please.

Thanks

UPDATE: How do I get previous or next section of the accordion?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $("#accordion").accordion({ 
   header: "h3.header"
   , autoHeight: false
   , collapsible: true
  });
</script>

<div id="accordion">
 <h3 class="header">Section 1</h3>
 <div> content 1 .. content 1 .. content 1 .. content 1 ..
  <input class="next" type="button" value="next"/>   
 </div>
 <h3 class="header">Section 2</h3>
 <div> content 2 .. content 2 .. content 2 .. content 2 ..
  <input class="previous" type="button" value="previous"/>
  <input class="next" type="button" value="next"/>   
 </div>
 <h3 class="header">Section 3</h3>
 <div> content 3 .. content 3 .. content 3 .. content 3 ..
  <input class="previous" type="button" value="previous"/>
 </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Can you mark one of the answers as accepted or did none of them work for you?

Comment: @Mateng - I used JQueryUI Accordion instead of the code in the question as none of the answers helped me back then.

Comment: jQueriUI Accordion is the successor of the jQuery accordion plugin. With jQueryUI, @johnjelineks solution works just fine. BTW: You can answer your own question, then mark it as correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to get it to work. Give this a shot, it works with jQuery 1.6 and jQuery UI 1.8:

HTML:

```
<div id="checkout">
    <h2><a href="#">Section 1</a></h2>
    <div>
        <form action="#">
            <h3>Content</h3>
            <input type="submit" class="next" value="Continue" />
        </form>
    </div>
    <h2><a href="#">Section 2</a></h2>
    <div>
        <form action="#">
            <h3>Content</h3>
            <input type="submit" class="prev" value="Back" />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // create new accordion
        var checkout = $('#checkout').accordion({ event: false });

        // assign accordion navigation events to button clicks
        $('form', checkout).each(function (index) {
            $(this)
            .children(':submit')
            .filter('.next, .prev')
            .click(function () {
                checkout.accordion('option', 'active', index + ($(this).is('.next') ? 1 : -1));
                return false;
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Very good, this works. I used it within a longer form - therefore I left out the form tags around the input buttons, and replaced the `$('form', checkout)` part with `$('div', checkout)`. (No nested forms allowed in HTML).

Answer (score 4):

Add this to your jQuery files. It adds a function $("#accordion").accordion("next") and an option, "loopOnNext" (default false) to force it to return to the top box when it's at the end.

```
$.extend($.ui.accordion.prototype, {
    next: function(){
        var index = this.option('active') || 0,
            next = index + 1,
        nodes = $(this.element).children('h3').length;
        if(next >= nodes && this.option('loopOnNext') === true) {
            next = 0;
        }

        return this.activate(next);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and used:

```
<button onclick="$('#accordion').accordion('activate', 0);">Prev</button>
<button onclick="$('#accordion').accordion('activate', 2);">Next</button>
```

on each accordion pane.  This is on the 2nd pane and brings you back to the first (index of 0) or forward to the third (index of 2).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to do just like in example?

```
var wizard = $("#accordion").accordion({ 
    header: 'h3.header', 
    event: false
}); 

$("h3.header", wizard).each(function(index) { 
    $(this) 
    .next() 
    .children(":button") 
    .filter(".next, .previous") 
    .click(function() { 
        wizard.changeAccordion("activate", index + ($(this).is(".next") ? 1 : -1)) 
    }); 
});
```

Comment: I tried but it gave error for changeAccordion function (not found). "This plugin is now part of jQuery UI and this standalone version won’t be updated anymore. The page will remain as a reference." 
So I am just using Jquery UI not the files from this plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a solution to the same problem and come up with this (I'm working with jQuery 1.4.2 and jQuery UI 1.8.1):

```
<div id="wizard">
    <h3><a href="#step1">Step 1 / 3</a></h3>
    <div id="step1">
        <button type="button">Next &raquo;</button>
    </div>
    <h3><a href="#step2">Step 2 / 3</a></h3>
    <div id="step2">
        <button type="button">Next &raquo;</button>
    </div>
    <h3><a href="#step3">Step 3 / 3</a></h3>
    <div id="step3">
        <button type="submit">Finish</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {

        $('#wizard').accordion();

        $('#wizard :button').each(function (index, elm) {
            $(elm).click(function() {
                $('#wizard').accordion('activate', index + 1);
            });
        });

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var wizard = $("#register_form").accordion({
    header: '.title',
    event: 'none',
    collapsible: false
});
$(':button.previous').click(function() { wizard.accordion("activate", 0); });
$(':button.next').click(function() { wizard.accordion("activate", 1); });
```

Where `:button` are the prev and next buttons, and `wizard` is your jQuery accordion.
Leave out all the other code. See if this works.
Please leave feedback, thanks.